# how to remove write protected system on usb?

Tags: usb, gparted, format, read-only

i have deleted a usb disk using Gparted , and i am trying to create new disk using the unlocated space .. and i found this message

```
Can't write to /dev/sdb, because it is opened read-only.
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb` will help?

Comment: Is this a USB pendrive (guessing from the size)? In that case, if it is read-only, whatever you try to do with it, you may have a big problem: it might be 'gridlocked'. See this link and links from it: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297 You can try to wipe the first megabyte and after that try with gparted again.

Comment: You should also try zeroing out the first few megabytes with `dd`.

Comment: Sometimes a dedicated gparted Live USB stick will do things that the version of gparted installed in Ubuntu will not. Your problem looks like it might be one of those occasions.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb

sudo umount /dev/sdb
```

Then go to Gparted and format the drive as FAT32.

Now it can be opened by Windows or any other operating system.